# VSCode and clickable paths within Docker containers

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode (1.10.2) integrated terminal, I can click on file paths to "jump to file". Unfortunately, I can't do that when working with a container-based stack (hear Docker Compose) as the displayed file paths are proper to the container volumes. Does anybody know if there's a way to configure / bind / map a localPath to a remotePath somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I implemented the links in VS Code's terminal*

There is no way to open remote paths like that within VS Code currently so the terminal cannot piggyback on such logic.

However, the link matcher functionality will eventually be exposed through the extension API which will allow extension authors to create their own link matchers and handle the clicks however they see fit. I can envision a docker container link matcher and handler that would download and open the files being implemented with such an API. Subscribe to [Microsoft/vscode#18454](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18454) for updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Marked your answer as accepted answer for now. I invite whoever to suggest an edit or comment in here when a solution is out there! I subscribed to the GitHub issue and will follow closely, eventually will work on a solution myself when it will be exposed through the extension API.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering and coding - looking at the bug, I couldn't tell if there are any customizations available for this sort of thing